# Does RPGLE has a ternary operator?

Tags: ternary-operator, rpgle

I did find old posts on forums about this question.  But as they were old, I was wondering if it changed.

I know that, back maybe in 2004, RPG did not have ternary operator.  Having work a bit in C# and Java, I did use them and I like them.  I was wondering if RPGLE eventually included them, somehow.

In C#, a ternary operation looks like this :

```
myvar = var1 > var2 ? var1 : var2;
```

So if var1 is greater than var2, myvar will get var1.  This was a basic example.

So... do you guys know if there's a ternary operator in RPGLE and if there is, what's its syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, RPGLE does not have ternary-operators.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzasd/expropt.htm

Comment: Thank you for the reference.  It would be a good addition to the language, though.

Comment: Submit it to COMMON as a requirement.  http://requirements.common.org/ideasIBM/index.htm

Answer (score 2):

ran across this function that emulates ternaries in RPGLE. also has some CLLE options listed.

https://www.itjungle.com/2005/11/09/fhg110905-story01/

```
D iif             pr           256a   varying                  
D  Condition                      n           value            
D  TrueValue                   256a   varying value            
D  FalseValue                  256a   varying value 
---------------------------------------------------
P iif             b                                    
D                 pi           256a   varying          
D  Condition                      n           value    
D  TrueValue                   256a   varying value    
D  FalseValue                  256a   varying value    
 /free                                                 
     if Condition;                                     
        return TrueValue;                              
     else;                                             
        return FalseValue;
endif;        
 /end-free         
P                 e
```

Answer (score 1):

No but you can use similar for setting an indicator (boolean) to true or false. I do it all the time. If below numberOne variable is defined as an integer with initial value of 1 and numberTwo with initial value of 2.

```
*in99 = numberOne < numberTwo
```

99 = true because above statement tests true, else 99 would equal false. This syntax replaces below

```
if numberOne < numberTwo
  *in99 = *on
else
  *in99 = *off
endif
```